# How does the return from PHP/MySQL get back into the calling page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've dummied up the page here: http://bsaroundtable.org/scota/testit.php All you need to do to run it is hit the submit button. A value is already supplied.
Below is the editDBlisting.php code that it is supposed to use to build (in this case) a table.

But I never get anything back except most of the echo("in the php, str = $q"); and then only the text and not the value of $q. So I understand that its not getting to the PHP. But why? I've tried GET instead of POST, plus nearly every other combination available.

This is nearly line for line what I'm doing in another place and it works perfectly so no doubt I've got a little error that I can't find. 
Please help me find the issue.

This time you can make fun of me for not seeing it.
{

```
/*  Title: editDBlisting.php
     Written: 2016=07-12
     Reference:
*/

    ini_set("display_errors",1); 
    error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

    require_once "dbConnectDtls.php";

    define("CONST_USER_TIMEZONE", "America/Chicago");
    /* server timezone */
    define("CONST_SERVER_TIMEZONE", "CST");

    /* server dateformat */
    define("CONST_SERVER_DATEFORMAT", "Y-m-d H:i:s");

    function now($str_user_timezone = CONST_USER_TIMEZONE,
       $str_server_timezone = CONST_SERVER_TIMEZONE,
       $str_server_dateformat = CONST_SERVER_DATEFORMAT) {

      // set timezone to user timezone
      date_default_timezone_set($str_user_timezone);

      $date = new DateTime("now");
      $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($str_server_timezone));
      $str_server_now = $date->format($str_server_dateformat);

      // return timezone to server default
      date_default_timezone_set($str_server_timezone);

      return $str_server_now;
    }

    $dttm_change  = now(CONST_USER_TIMEZONE,CONST_SERVER_TIMEZONE,CONST_SERVER_DATEFORMAT);

        $q = $_POST["str"];

        echo("in the php, str = $q");

        $stmt = $db_found->prepare("SELECT * FROM SCOTA WHERE edit_code = '$q' ");

        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

        foreach($result as $row) {

            echo ("<table id='feedback'>
            <col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col>
            <thead style='text-align: center;'>
                <tr>
                    <th>CRN</th>
                    <th>Registrar</th>
                    <th>Call Sign</th>
                    <th>eMail</th>
                    <th>Youth</th>
                    <th>Adult</th>
                    <th>Camp Name</th>
                    <th>Official</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                </tr></thead><tbody><tr>");

            echo ("<td class=\"edit\" id=\"campRegNumber:$row[id]\">$row[campRegNumber] </td>");
            echo ("<td class=\"edit\" id=\"name:$row[id]\">$row[name] </td>");
            echo ("<td class=\"edit\" id=\"callSign:$row[id]\">$row[callSign] </td>");
            echo ("<td class=\"edit\" id=\"eMail:$row[id]\">$row[eMail] </td>");

            echo ("<td class=\"edit\" id=\"adultCount:$row[id]\">$row[adultCount] </td>");
            echo ("<td class=\"edit\" id=\"youthCount:$row[id]\">$row[youthCount] </td>");
            echo ("<td class=\"edit\" id=\"campName:$row[id]\">$row[campName] </td>");

            echo ("<td class=\"edit\" id=\"official_scout_camp:$row[id]\">$row[official_scout_camp] </td>");
            echo ("<td class=\"edit\" id=\"city:$row[id]\">$row[city] </td>");
            echo ("</tr></tbody></table>");
            echo ("<br><br>");

            echo ("<table id='feedback'>
            <col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col><col>
            <thead style='text-align: center;'>
                <tr>
                    <th>State</th>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <th>Latitude</th>
                    <th>Longitude</th>
                    <th>Grid</th>
                    <th>Power</th>
                    <th>Date Start</th>
                    <th>Time Start</th>
                    <th>Time End</th>
                    <th>Date End</th>
                    <th>Comments</th>
                </tr>
            </thead><tbody><tr>");
            echo ("<td class=\"edit\" id=\"state:$row[id]\">$row[state] </td>");
            echo ("<td class=\"edit\" id=\"country:$row[id]\">$row[country] </td>");
            echo ("<td class=\"edit\" id=\"latitude:$row[id]\">$row[latitude] </td>");
            echo ("<td class=\"edit\" id=\"longitude:$row[id]\">$row[longitude] </td>");
            echo ("<td class=\"edit\" id=\"grid:$row[id]\">$row[grid] </td>");
            echo ("<td class=\"edit\" id=\"power:$row[id]\">$row[power] </td>");
            echo ("<td class=\"edit\" id=\"dateStart:$row[id]\">$row[dateStart] </td>");
            echo ("<td class=\"edit\" id=\"timeStart:$row[id]\">$row[timeStart] </td>");
            echo ("<td class=\"edit\" id=\"timeEnd:$row[id]\">$row[timeEnd] </td>");
            echo ("<td class=\"edit\" id=\"dateEnd:$row[id]\">$row[dateEnd] </td>");
            echo ("<td class=\"edit\" id=\"comments:$row[id]\">$row[comments] </td>");

        }

        echo ("</tr></tbody></table>"); 

?>
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is more than one mistakes, but what I can see is that in the form on the page `testit.php` you have set name of input to `getCode`, but in `editDBlisting.php` you have line `$q = $_POST['str'];` instead of `$q = $_POST['getCode'];`

Comment: Sometimes the simplest thing becomes invisible. This fixed it, thank you so much. Four eyes are just so much better than two.